# SQL: Two queries in a single set of results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6. I have three tables, like this:

```
Table public.user
id      integer
name    character varying
email   character varying

Table public.project
id      integer
user_id integer 

Table public.sale
id      integer
user_id integer
```

`user_id` is a foreign key in both the `project` and `sale` tables.

Is there a way I can get a list back of all user IDs with the number of projects and number of sales attached to them, as a single query?

So I'd like final data that looks like this:

```
user_id,num_projects,num_stories
121,28,1
122,43,6
123,67,2
```

I know how to do just the number of projects:

```
SELECT "user".id, COUNT(*) AS num_visualisations 
JOIN project ON project.user_id="user".id
GROUP BY "user".id
ORDER BY "user".id DESC
```

But I don't know how also to get the number of sales too, in a single query.

Comment: I'm sure this will be a duplicate *answer*, but I have searched and I don't think it's a duplicate *question*, in the way I've expressed it - so please leave it open, to help others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries for the aggregation and a `left join`:

```
select u.*, p.num_projects, s.num_sales
from user u left join
     (select p.user_id, count(*) as num_projects
      from projects p
      group by p.user_id
     ) p
     on p.user_id = u.id left join
     (select s.user_id, count(*) as num_sales
      from sales s
      group by s.user_id
     ) s
     on s.user_id = u.id;
```

Comment: @Richard . . . Absolutely.  That is why the query uses `left join`.